# SVN troubles. How do I move latest two commits to branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

Basically,

I have made two commits in the last month which were prototype code. (yes I know, never commit anything not working, to the trunk). But as Im the only one working on it, it was more of a backup than anything.

The problem is that I had to then making needed changes.

To do this I had to checkout the version before this was added. And made changes.

What I want to do now, is commit the before code, with new changes to trunk. But not have the prototype code there.. Aka move it to a branch where it belongs.

So basically, Im looking at a way to **move latest two commits to a branch instead**, so that I can commit this new code.

I Am using visualSVN server, and eclipse svn.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually voted to close as I think this is off-topic, but just in case, here is what I would do: branch the current trunk to a new branch. Check out the trunk from the last revision before you made the prototype changes, make the changes you actually want, and commit that back to the trunk.

Comment: I cant commit without updating though. I want rid of the two new commits on the trunk. Your branch idea is good, idk why I didnt think of it. Oh I'll need to update before branch, so getting collegue to do it, so i Dont lose new code.

Comment: OK, so first create a patch containing the differences you want. Then check out the trunk from the current revision (call that curr_trunk), and the trunk from the revision you want to revert to (call that old_trunk). Manually copy the changed files from old_trunk to curr_trunk. Commit that (that gives you the rollback). Then apply your patch and commit that.